# Foreach Php me repite la insercion de registros

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

Estoy realizando un aplicativo php con mysqli para la gestion de una carta restaurant donde cada plato puede tener varios precios y medidas.
Tengo un form que me trae datos en un array para insertar en una base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
$arrPrecios = array() {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(13) "Porcion 250gr"
    ["precio"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "165"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(13) "Porcion 600gr"
    ["precio"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "199"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(13) "Super Porcion"
    ["precio"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
}
```

A su vez, realizo la consulta a la base de datos para saber que precios de los que trae el array anterior ya se encuentran alli, comparando los id de cada uno, generandome otro array asi:

```
    $pp = array() {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "18"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "165"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "165"
  }
}
```

La comprobacion la realizao mediante un foreach, asi:

```
//guardar precios
                                    foreach ($arrPrecios as $values) {

                                        foreach ($pp as $ppid) {

                                            if ($values['id'] == $ppid[0]) {

                                                $precioId = $values['id'];
                                                $precioMedida = $values['medida'];
                                                $precioPrecio = $values['precio'];

                                                $sqlPrecio = "UPDATE carta_precios SET medida='$precioMedida',precio='$precioPrecio',segun_mercado='$segun_mercado',estado='0' WHERE id='$precioId'";
                                                $dao->exec($sqlPrecio);

                                            } else {

                                            $precioMedida2 = $values['medida'];
                                            $precioPrecio2 = $values['precio'];
                                            $sqlPrecioInsert = "INSERT INTO carta_precios (id,medida,precio,segun_mercado,carta_platos_id,estado) VALUES (null,'$precioMedida2','$precioPrecio2','','$id_plato','0')";
                                            //var_dump($sqlPrecioInsert); exit();
                                            $dao->exec($sqlPrecioInsert);

                                            }

                                        }

                                    }
```

El problema es que me genera dos registros ya que el foreach del $pp pasa dos veces, eso lo entiendo, pero no me comprueba si el valor ya existe en la base de datos.
Cualquier sugerencia o solucion es bienvenida.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Checa que tu id sea no nula y que sea única y obvio autoincremental, por lo que veo no es asi, y verifica de igual manera tu if, estas realmente comparando números o strings, ya que lo que trae el foreach son strings

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu problema, pero intuyo que hay un error de lógica ante todo. Las bases de datos son relacionales, por lo tanto, deberías, a partir de una información determinada, traer otro tipo de información relacionada con ella **en una sola consulta**. No entendí si estás usando un array para verificar por cada elemento en la base de datos ¿? Si es así, es una barbaridad, eso contradice el concepto *relacional*  de las bases de datos y podria ser muy costoso en ciertos contextos. Sea como sea, la pregunta no es clara y eso no ayuda a darte una solución óptima para tu caso.

Comment: Échale un ojo a la sentencia ['INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)